# Solution of elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory

I am working on Diophantine equations. I found that calculation of  S-Integral points on elliptic curve has been done by MAGMA for equation $x^2 + 2^a.$ $5^b = y^n$ where $\gcd(x, y) = 1$, $a\ge 0,$ $b\ge0,$ $x \ge1,$ and $y \ge 1$. Since MAGMA is not an open source software so it is difficult to find solution. I just want to ask you is there any other software through which calculation of S integral points on elliptic curve can be done ?
Please help me with this.

Comment: [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6676/15503) links resources for Sage. There might be something that helps you there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but let it be here.

It will not solve the problem for a general $n$, and for all possible values of $a,b$, but it shows how to use [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) to obtain experimental / proven data when $n$ is $3$, so that we have a direct relation to an elliptic curve. (Well, for $n=1$, and even $n=2$ the situation is simple. The case $n=4$ also corresponds to an elliptic curve after rational transformation, but integral points are possibly not conserved, this case will not be touched below.)

To fix ideas, we will compute all integral points, and the rank of the corresponding elliptic curves $$Y^2=X^3-2^a\cdot 5^b$$ (so $n=3$) for $0\le a\le 3$ and $0\le b\le 3$. (Note that i had to change the role of the letters $x,y$ into $Y,X$ to better fit with the usual notations.

The following sage code:

```
for a in [0..3]:
    for b in [0..3]:
        E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [0,-2^a*5^b])
        print("\na={} b={}\nE: {}".format(a,b,E))
        print("E has rank {}".format(E.rank()))
        points = E.integral_points()
        if not points:
            print("NO Integral points.")
            continue    # with the next b

        # else we are in business
        if len(points) == 1:
            print("There is one integral point:")
        else:
            print("There are {} integral points:".format(len(points)))
        for P in points:
            print('\t{}'.format(P.xy()))
```

delivers then

```
a=0 b=0
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 1 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
There is one integral point:
        (1, 0)

a=0 b=1
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 5 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
NO Integral points.

a=0 b=2
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 25 over Rational Field
E has rank 1
There is one integral point:
        (5, 10)

a=0 b=3
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 125 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
There is one integral point:
        (5, 0)

a=1 b=0
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 2 over Rational Field
E has rank 1
There is one integral point:
        (3, 5)

a=1 b=1
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 10 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
NO Integral points.

a=1 b=2
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 50 over Rational Field
E has rank 1
NO Integral points.

a=1 b=3
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 250 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
NO Integral points.

a=2 b=0
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 4 over Rational Field
E has rank 1
There are 2 integral points:
        (2, 2)
        (5, 11)

a=2 b=1
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 20 over Rational Field
E has rank 1
There is one integral point:
        (6, 14)

a=2 b=2
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 100 over Rational Field
E has rank 1
There are 3 integral points:
        (5, 5)
        (10, 30)
        (34, 198)

a=2 b=3
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 500 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
NO Integral points.

a=3 b=0
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 8 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
There is one integral point:
        (2, 0)

a=3 b=1
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 40 over Rational Field
E has rank 1
There is one integral point:
        (14, 52)

a=3 b=2
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 200 over Rational Field
E has rank 2
There are 3 integral points:
        (6, 4)
        (9, 23)
        (66, 536)

a=3 b=3
E: Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 1000 over Rational Field
E has rank 0
There is one integral point:
        (10, 0)
```

The question was addressing also the computation of $S$-integral points, below i am giving some experimental code for $S=[2,5]$, my guess of an interesting set of "bad primes".
The code omits the already displayed integral points, shows only the $S$-integral, non-integral points in case of a *minimal* $E$.

Code:

```
import traceback
for (a,b) in cartesian_product([[0..8], [0..8]]):
    E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [0,-2^a*5^b])
    if not E.is_minimal():
        continue
    try:
        points = E.integral_points()
        points_S = E.S_integral_points([2, 5])
        if set(points) != set(points_S):
            print("\n{}".format(E))
            print("S-integral points which are not integral:".format(len(points)))
            print('\t{}'.format(', '.join([str(P.xy())
                                           for P in points_S
                                           if P not in points])))
    except Exception:
        # traceback.print_exc()
        print('\nCase a={} b={} needs a more dedicated code... sorry!'.format(a, b))
```

Results:

```
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 25 over Rational Field
S-integral points which are not integral:
        (65/16, 415/64)

Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 2 over Rational Field
S-integral points which are not integral:
        (129/100, 383/1000)

Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 100 over Rational Field
S-integral points which are not integral:
        (185/4, 2515/8)

Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 200 over Rational Field
S-integral points which are not integral:
        (681/4, 17771/8)

Case a=3 b=5 needs a more dedicated code... sorry!

Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 10000 over Rational Field
S-integral points which are not integral:
        (425/4, 8725/8)
```

For $n=4$ the situation is slightly more complicated.

This answer is only given a starting point to further experiments / investigations, hope it helps...

Comment: Looks like a lot. $(+1)$